# Jetpack compose change in uiState doesn't trigger recomposition

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state, android-jetpack

I think I haven't quite wrapped my head around how compose states work yet. I'm not able to trigger a recomposition when an item in the uiState changes.

I'm building an app that need notification access, so for that I'm navigating the user to the settings and after the user has granted permission they have to navigate back to the app. That's where I want to trigger the recomposition.

I have the permission check in onResume working and the variable in the uiState changes, but the recomposition doesn't get called. What am I missing here?

**Composable**

```
@Composable
private fun MainLayout(viewModel: SetupViewModel){
    val uiState = viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    SetupItem(
        title = "Notification access",
        summary = if(uiState.value.hasNotificationPermission) stringResource(R.string.granted) else stringResource(R.string.not_granted){}
}
```

**SetupUiState.kt**

```
data class SetupUiState(
    var hasNotificationPermission: Boolean = false
)
```

I know for a fact that `hasNotificationPermission` gets set to true, but the summary in the SetupItem does not update. How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem here is that the `hasNotificationPermission` field is mutable (`var` and not `val`). Compose is not tracking inner fields for change. You have two options here:

1. Modify the SetupUiState as a whole, assuming you are using StateFlow in your ViewModel, it can look like this:

   ```
   fun setHasNotificationPermission(value: Boolean) {
       uiState.update { it.copy(hasNotificationPermission = value) }
   }
   ```

   You should also change `hasNotificationPermission` from var to val.
2. You can make use of compose's `State` and do something like this:

   ```
   class SetupUiState(
       initialHasPermission: Boolean = false
   ) {
       var hasNotificationPermission: Boolean by mutableStateOf(initialHasPermission)
   }
   ```

   With this you can then simply do `uiState.hasNotificationPermission = value` and composition will be notified, since it's tracking `State` instances automatically.